# How to programmatically dismiss quasar notification

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Confused with quasar documentation. Not sure what that means

From docs: Notifications are meant to be dismissed only by the user, however for exceptional cases you can do it programmatically. Especially useful when you set indefinite timeout (0).

```
const dismiss = $q.notify({...})
...
dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who got confused with documentation as much as i did

`$q.notify(...)` returns you another function, you can leave it as is, call it with no parameters to hide the said notification, or call with some parameters to update the said notification

```
$q.notify({ message: 'I am a regular notification, will open and close as usual' })

const dismiss = $q.notify({ message: 'I will hide programmatically', timeout: 0 // Optionally set timeout to 0 to fully control the dismissing })

setTimeout(() => {
  dismiss() // will hide the notification above
}, Math.random() * 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused about the documentation.
My issue was to create something which indicates if the backend server is down. See the snippet out of my code in Typescript:

```
const serverdown = ref(false)
const $q = useQuasar()
let notification: ((props?: QNotifyUpdateOptions | undefined) => void) | null = null

function serverDownToggle() {
  notification = $q.notify({
    spinner: true,
    message: 'Server down',
    color: 'red',
    timeout: 0,
    position: 'top',
  });
}


watch(serverdown, (newValue) => {
  if (newValue) {
    serverDownToggle();
  } else {
    // Dismiss the notification
    notification && notification()
    }
});
```

In this solution the `notification()` is called as the name of the constant.
Instead of the `watch` of course you can use any other trigger e.g. click from a button outside the notification.